# Is it possible to download entire git commit history as a list?

Tags: git

We need this list to overview/analyze contributor commitment to to the project. Any format is just fine. We need commit text, date, user.

Comment: `git log > history.txt` ?

Comment: Type `git help log` in your terminal or read the documentation of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/log) online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git log` command to get the details about all the commits.

You can also use the options available to get details about a specific author or your specific requirements.

```
git log --author=<name or email>
```

The output of `git log` looks like

```
Change version number1
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

Change version number
commit 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 16:40:33 2008 -0700

Remove unnecessary test
commit a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 10:31:28 2008 -0700
```

Reference: [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)